# "Pattern not found" in Vim searching for HTML text

Tags: regex, vim

I am editing an HTML document containing the line:

```
<h2>Table of Contents</h2>
```

and many other lines like it. My cursor is currently placed at the beginning of this line. The command

```
:%s!<h2>(.+)</h2>!<h2><a name="#link">$1</a></h2>!g
```

Elicits

```
E486: Pattern not found: <h2>(.+)</h2>
```

And the results are similar if I try to escape the parentheses for the capture group, or even omit them entirely:

```
:%s!<h2>\(.+\)</h2>!<h2><a name="#link">$1</a></h2>!g
E486: Pattern not found: <h2>\(.+\)</h2>
:%s!<h2>.+</h2>!<h2><a name="#link">$1</a></h2>!g
E486: Pattern not found: <h2>.+</h2>
```

Can someone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the `+`.  The one or more quantifier in Vim is `\+`, you are searching for a literal `+`.  Also the back reference in is `\` not `$` so your replacement string should be:

```
:%s!<h2>\(.\+\)</h2>!<h2><a name="#link">\1</a></h2>!g
```

If you have more than one `<h2>` tag on a line, this replacement will be wrong.  It will match from the start of the first `<h2>` to the end of the last `</h2>`.

To fix that you need to use a non-greedy match, which will match as few characters as possible rather than as many an possible:

```
:%s!<h2>\(.\{-}\)</h2>!<h2><a name="#link">\1</a></h2>!g
```

Comment: Vim golf: `%s!<h2>\zs.\{-}\ze</h2>!<a name="#link">&</a>!g`